# req.body undefined on server side

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am working on app which uses **node, express, mysql** on server side. i have written serveral APIs on server.js file and when i am trying to access those using Postman then **req.body** is always undefined.

this is my server.js configuration.

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var wrench = require("wrench");
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require("path");
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var walk = require('walk');
var fse = require('fs-extra');
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();
var crypto = require('crypto');

app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb',extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'pass',
    database: 'dbname'
});


connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... \n\n");
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... \n\n");
    }
});

app.post('/urlreq', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
}
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Rest Demo Listening on port 3000");
});
```

When i am trying send something in body in Postman then req.body is coming empty on server side.

Comment: Are you sending `multipart/form-data` request? If so, it doesn't work because `bodyparser` doesn't handle this body type

Comment: Typo in `app.listem` change it to `app.listen`

Comment: @ Curious i am not using multipart for form-data justing sending form data as object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sending `multipart/form-data`, it doesn't work because `bodyparser` doesn't handle this body type.

In this case adding the following line should fix it:

```
app.use(multipartMiddleware);
```

Form the [docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests):

> `multipart/form-data` is the default encoding a web form uses to transfer data

Answer (score 0):

You can use as a middleware also. Also listen on a port. add following lines in your code -

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {      
  console.log('Current User:', req.body);
  next();
});

app.post('/url', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but still same prob. is  coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try add:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
[...]

// Last stack
app.listen(3000, function(){ 
    console.log("Rest Demo Listening on port 3000"); 
});
```