# Http request with angular 2 not beeing sent

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular

In my **server** I got this:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){

    //TODO: vaidate request

    console.log("req:",res);

    var query = req.query;

    console.log("query",query);

});
```

In my browser I have this:

```
//var to_send = ({"username": username, "password": password});
var to_send = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;

  var headers = new Headers();
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8080/', to_send, {
        headers: headers
      })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      response => this.returned = data,
      () => console.log('Request sent')
    );
return "";
```

The request is received but no arguments I sent are shown in the console log. I tried sending them in json and in url-encoding, both implemented in the code. Any ideia? Thank you very much for your help!

**EDIT:**

Here is my new code, still failing:

```
var to_send = JSON.stringify({"username": username, "password": password});
//var to_send = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;

  var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    //headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8080/', to_send, {
        headers: headers
      })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      response => this.returned = data,
      () => console.log('Request sent')
    );
return "";
```

So, any ideas? :(

Comment: I'm kinda new to node.js as well, but wouldn't it be `req.body` ?

Comment: @lexith that gives undefined

Comment: when you try it with the `application/json` and the `to_send` in json format as well?

Comment: and to rule that one out, you're using `bodyParser` or an equivalent?

Comment: @lexith nope, just the code above, directly searching in req. Please check my edit in the question...

Comment: Take a look at this question and the usage of the `body-parser` module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630614/req-body-undefined-on-server-side It seems to be an issue on your server side.

Comment: @lexith I installed package body-parser. How exactly should I use it in my code? (in a specific example)

Comment: Is the server script even receiving the request? Try setting a custom header: `headers.append('X-Header','myVal')` and on the server side log request headers to the console. Also is the returned value received by the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use bodyParser ?:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Then:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res){

    var query = req.body;

    console.log("Query: ", query);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to send as payload data, or in the URL string? Because you're doing a mix of both. I think you probably want to send it as payload data, according to your `http.post()`.

You need to define the payload data as json instead of a string that would be tacked onto the URL.

```
var to_send = {username: 'username', password: 'password'}
```

and then in your post request you need to stringify the JSON I believe `JSON.stringify(to_send)` as the second argument.

If you are trying to put it on the URL, then you'd need to put null as the second argument, and append that string to your URL to send the request to.

Comment: he tried it, but its commented out in his question.

Comment: I am not mixing both. I switch the comments of both at the same time. I send json.stringify with its header or I send url-form encoded with "example=hamburger&..."

Comment: Well he's right. the `JSON.stringify()` is missing in your question. better update it if you have that in your actual code since it won't work without it.

Comment: He doesn't need to stringify it in the original question, as he is sending a content-type of "application/x-www-form-urlencode" the initial example looks valid on the request side

Comment: @JohnAckerman he added both variants (just one of them commented out).

Comment: Looking at it, I think the problem must be on the node server side, the angular request looks fine to me. Unfortunately I don't have any good suggestions on node....